# Capacity for ubuntu

Tags: mac, ssd, ubuntu-netbook

I want to install ubuntu on an external SSD. The drive is 120GB. I want to split it into 2 partitions. One for a hackintosh and the other for ubuntu. Will 40GB be sufficient for ubuntu to run smoothly ?

Comment: Whether it'll run **smoothly** doesn't really depend on the disk space... But you'll be able to install it in 40GB, and have plenty of space left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum disk space required for ubuntu is about 7Gb. With 40Gb your system is will work very well.

(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME)